# I can't seem to get this message to go away and it won't let me commit changes

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control, git-bash

So, I was trying to commit to my repo and for some reason, this message keeps it from committing.

`hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: code: command not found error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'. Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.`

I tried this code

`it config --global core.editor "code --wait"`

but it doesn't seem to work. I'm still learning git so I'm probably learning this wrong.

Comment: It seems the `code` command's location is not in the PATH variable when git runs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bvisual-studio-code%5D+not+found